# I'm starting out using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am just starting out to use tkinter in Python 3.5 and I don't understand it the best yet but hopefully will over time.
Anyway, what I was asking was how do I create a text box that a user can type into, I know it is possible but don't yet know how to execute this as, as I said at the beginning, I'm just starting out.
If there is any scaffolding code of a box that I could use to that would allow a user to enter text, it would be a great help if you could show it to me.
Also, to interact with this input, would it be the same as python?

I know this is a lot to be asking but any responses are welcome,
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Attach a Text widget to a Frame

Comment: Is there any reason you are posting this on Stack Overflow rather than reading though a tutorial?

Comment: Answers to your questions are readily available in almost every tkinter tutorial. You need to attempt to solve the problem yourself before asking a question.  See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/7432)

Answer (score 1):

Both of the following links contain code relating to text entry.

http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm

http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm

Entry is a single line box.
Text is a multiple line box and supports text formatting